# Wordpress - Working permalinks but 500 error displayed with Images

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, web-config, permalinks, internal-server-error

I've been struggling for 2 days trying to solve this below:

**Issue: 500 - "Internal server error. There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."**

In the beginning, my permalinks would receive a 404 error when changing to "pretty permalinks" - I resolved this by having this code below which I found on the net:

```
# BEGIN WordPress

RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

# END Wordpress
```

I received a message when changing my permalinks structure that I should "update my web.config file now" as well, which I did below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<configuration>

<system.webServer>

<rewrite>

<rules>

<rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">

<match url="*"/>

<conditions>

<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>

<add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>

</conditions>

<action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>

</rule></rules>

</rewrite>

</system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Awesome! Now my "Pretty Permalinks" are now working - except now I have an issue where if I upload any of my NEW images to the media gallery - the image uploads but I am not able to view the image in the attachment page nor anywhere on the site. When I open and go into the image URL, it displays -

**"500 - Internal server error.
There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."**

**And when I click on the Image, it displays - "The image could not be loaded"**

All my old images are 100% working, it's just my newly uploaded Images that receive this error.

*To note: When I remove the web.config file, the newly added images are resolved but I then receive the **"404 - File directory not found"** when I'm on "Pretty Permalinks"*

Please is anyone able to give me some insight to what may be the cause?

I'm quite a rookie when it comes to this so be nice :)

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the error logs yet?

Comment: This is the only thing that shows up in the log file -
PHP Warning:  call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'new_user_email_admin_notice' not found or invalid function name in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\**------------**\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 298